# Cannot check or uncheck DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cells programmatically on UI

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

i've a DataGridView on which i've added a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn.
I've also addedd two buttons one for select all the checkBox and one for de-select all the  checkBox.

Cell click and select/deselect all buttons works separately, but doesn't works if, for example, i select a cell with mouse click (check box is selected on UI) and then if i press the deselect-All button the value of checkboxs changed but the checkboxs on UI stay checked.

here is my code
Cell Click

```
 private void dictionaryDataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.ColumnIndex == dictionaryDataGrid.Columns["ColSel"].Index) && (e.RowIndex >= 0))
             dictionaryDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColSel"].Value = !(bool)(dictionaryDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColSel"].Value == null ? false : dictionaryDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColSel"].Value);

    }
```

button select all:

```
 private void btn_selAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dictionaryDataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dictionaryDataGrid.Rows[i - 1].Cells["ColSel"].Value = true;
            }
        }
```

button deselect all:

```
private void btn_unselAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= dictionaryDataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dictionaryDataGrid.Rows[i - 1].Cells["ColSel"].Value = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    private void btn_unselAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dictionaryDataGrid.ClearSelection();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dictionaryDataGrid.Rows)
            {
                ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["ColSel"]).Value = false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i've tried but doesn't work. I've solved changing the editModo to programmatically.